# Detect click on HTML option tag through javascript in Android WebView

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

I have a form in a webview. I'm able to detect button clicks and perform required tasks.But in the form, there is a option tag. Based on the selected item type, I should perform next task. But I'm unable to detect the option click event. I tried both with onClick and onChange. Both doesn't work. Any idea how to detect its click event?

I tried the below code in my html code:

```
  <div class="label"><b>Type :</b></div>
            <div class="field">
                <select name="type" >
                    <option value="video" selected="selected" onchange="videos.performClick()">video</option>
                    <option value="image" onchange="images.performClick()">image</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to listen for `onchange` event on select field.

```
<div class="label"><b>Type :</b></div>
        <div class="field">
            <select name="type" onchange="onSelectFieldChange(this)">
                <option value="video" selected="selected">video</option>
                <option value="image">image</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now you write `onSelectFieldChange` function which handles redirection based on the selected option.

```
    function onSelectFieldChange(element) {

        switch(element.value) {
        case 'video':
            videos.performClick()
            break;
        case 'image':
            images.performClick()
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

    }
```

Comment: @ Vigneswaran Marimuthu, sometimes even though I have selected the option type,  javascript  doesn't get called. Why is this is happening..is there anything specific that ahs to be done?

Comment: @AmandaFernandez If you select the same option which is already selected, then `onchange` won't be called.

Comment: I know..I'm getting this issue at this scenario.                                                      1. When I select the type, the corresponding types gets selected and shows me the filechooser.                                                                                            2. There is a upload button in my webview. after clicking on the that the page loads again. After that onchange never gets called.

Comment: @AmandaFernandez Can you tell me which scenario ? I couldn't get what you meant by "at this scenario".